# How to disable Label in OutlinedtextField - Android - Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, material-design, android-jetpack-compose-material3

How can I set the OutlinedTextField to show only placeholder text, I dont't want it to show the hint label in top of textfield when focused!

Currently I am migrating my project from XML/Kotlin to Jetpack compose, Here When trying to replicate the EditText Design in Compose I faced this Difficulty, where I can't disable textField Hint label.

[image: This is what I need to Achieve]

[image: This is what I get]

Any answer would Be helpful! Thanks a Lot in Advance!

[This is my Code for OutlinedTextField](https://gist.github.com/SanjayAIT16/1adaa2552e29b9089ec2690cc4d64cbe)

Comment: show your jetpack compose code

Comment: @KishanViramgama I have added Code for your reference!

Comment: Use placeholder property instead of label.